# Error in for loop in ELO rating algorithm

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, rating

I'm trying to run the ELO rating code from here

https://github.com/xsankar/hairy-octo-hipster/blob/master/ELO-538.R

The dataset I'm using is here

https://www.mediafire.com/file/0a5v393ki775vw9/sport2.xlsx/file

The code I'm running is slightly modificated, I'm working with only 17 weeks instead of 22 as in the original code, but I could not make it work either with 22 weeks

```
##########################################################

library(dplyr)

data<- read_xlsx("C:/User/sport2.xlsx")
 
data$PtsW <- as.numeric(data$PtsW)
data$PtsL <- as.numeric(data$PtsL)
data$YdsW <- as.numeric(data$YdsW)
data$YdsL <- as.numeric(data$YdsL)
data$TOW <- as.numeric(data$TOW)
data$TOL <- as.numeric(data$TOL)

rankings <- data_frame()
teams <- data %>% distinct(Winner.tie) %>% select(Winner.tie)
teams
rankings <- bind_rows(rankings,teams)
#print(data)
#class(rankings)
#print(rankings)
rankings

for (i in 2:19) {
  rankings[,i] <- 0
}
colnames(rankings) <- c("Team","Week.0","Week.1","Week.2","Week.3","Week.4","Week.5","Week.6",
                        "Week.7","Week.8","Week.9","Week.10","Week.11","Week.12","Week.13",
                        "Week.14","Week.15","Week.16","Week.17")
rankings$Week.0 <- 1500

# Iterate for each week of play
week.no <- 1
k_factor <- 20.0
week.data <- data[data$Week == week.no,]


for (j in 1:17) {
  week.no <- j
  k_factor <- 20.0
  week.data <- data[data$Week == week.no,]
  for (i in 1:nrow(week.data)) {
    winner <- week.data[i,"Winner.tie"]
 
    loser <- week.data[i,"Loser.tie"]
    old.rank.w <- rankings[rankings$Team == winner,week.no+1]
    old.rank.w <- old.rank.w[[1]]
    old.rank.l <- rankings[rankings$Team == loser,week.no+1]
    old.rank.l <- old.rank.l[[1]]
    
    # Calculate Margin of Victory Multiplier 
    # mv_mult = LN(ABS(PD)+1) * (2.2/((ELOW-ELOL)*.001+2.2))
    pd <- week.data$PtsW[i] - week.data$PtsL[i]
    mv_mult <- 1 #Margin For Victory Multiplier
    mv_mult <- log(pd +1) * (2.2/((old.rank.w - old.rank.l)*.001+2.2))
    #
    
    # Use old ELO Algorithm
    #
    w_w <- 1.0
    w_l <- 0.0
    if (pd == 0) {
      w_w <- 0.5
      w_l <- 0.5
    }
    #
    
    #
    d_ij_w <- old.rank.w - old.rank.l
    d_ij_l <- old.rank.l - old.rank.w
    #
    mu_ij_w <- 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((-1 * d_ij_w)/400))
    new.rank.w <- round( old.rank.w + (k_factor * mv_mult * (w_w - mu_ij_w)))
    #
    mu_ij_l <- 1 / (1 + 10 ^ ((-1 * d_ij_l)/400))
    new.rank.l <- round( old.rank.l + (k_factor * mv_mult * (w_l - mu_ij_l)))
    #
    print (sprintf("Rank : W = %d L = %d",new.rank.w,new.rank.l))
    rankings[rankings$Team == winner,week.no+2] <- new.rank.w
    rankings[rankings$Team == loser,week.no+2] <- new.rank.l
  } 
  
###################################################################3  
  # if team didn't play, carry forward early ratings
  # not needed for wildcard, division et al
#  for (i in 1:nrow(rankings)) {
#    if (is.na(rankings[i,week.no+2])) {
#      rankings[i,week.no+2] <- rankings[i,week.no+1]
#    }
#    if (rankings[i,week.no+2] < 1) {
#      rankings[i,week.no+2] <- rankings[i,week.no+1]
#    }
#    }
##################################################################

}
# week #1 ranking
rankings %>% select(Team,Week.1) %>% arrange(-Week.1)
# week #17 ranking
rankings %>% select(Team,Week.17) %>% arrange(-Week.17)
#
```

I'm getting the error

```
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

I've tried modifying the for indexes and debugging but couldn't find what's wrong

Comment: As always, making the example reproducible will help you get answers. You should include the `curl::curl_download` operation, and load the package used to read the excel file.

Comment: Can you include only the code which is relevant so that we don't have to go through 100 lines of code to find an error. Make this example minimal as well as reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will echo Ronak's comment about the benefits of providing minimally reproducible examples such that we can help you better (meaning we don't have to comb through many lines of code to find the source of the error)!

**Before getting in the solution, I just wanted to point out a couple of stylistic coding "best" practices:**

- If you choose to use dplyr (and subsequently the tidyverse), it's usually stylistically more consistent to stick with it. Your code switches between dplyr and base, which can make the code more difficult to read, but it's not the end of the world
- When you use `read_xlsx()`, note that it's calling from the `readxl` package, which wasn't loaded as a library in your example nor referenced via namespacing, i.e. `readxl::read_xlsx()`. It's good practice to ensure that your example is fully reproducible with the packages that you use

**Code Rewrite**

I have rewritten part of your code in `dplyr` up until the source of the error.

```
data_clean <- data %>%
  mutate(across(c("PtsW":"TOL"), as.numeric))

teams <- data_clean %>% 
  distinct(Winner.tie) %>% 
  select(Winner.tie)
rankings <- teams
```

However, some fixes you can try implementing on your own are:

- rewriting the remainder of your code in the `dplyr` style
- using the `purrr` family of `map()` functions to replace the for loops. I still have yet to come across clear evidence that `purrr::map()` is *universally* faster than for loops, and I personally think using for loops are fundamentally instructive.

**Source of Error**

I believe the source of the error came from this part of your code:

```
winner <- week.data[i,"Winner.tie"]
loser <- week.data[i,"Loser.tie"]
```

When I printed `loser`, instead of getting a value "Green Bay Packers" in the first iteration of your inner loop (i = 1), I got a tibble, which is what your code is doing by indexing. The rest of the code fails because you then try to pass a tibble into this statement: `old.rank.l <- rankings[rankings$Team == loser,week.no+1]` and that returns an empty value (numeric(0)).

**Solution**

Here is the code rewrite up until the source of the error.

```
winner <- week.data[i,"Winner.tie"] %>% pull()
loser <- week.data[i,"Loser.tie"] %>% pull()
old.rank.w <- rankings %>%
  filter(Team == winner) %>%
  .[[week.no + 1]]
old.rank.l <- rankings %>%
  filter(Team == loser) %>%
  .[[week.no + 1]]
```

After making this change, running the rest of the code should work. Let me know if you have any questions

**Concluding Thoughts**

Use `print()` statements to see where your code is failing and also whether your objects contain values that you expect. When you start functionalizing your code, `browser()` is a useful debugging tool.